# How to reset app when sent to background

Tags: ios

I'm building a couple of simple calculator apps and I want to be able to restore it to the initial setting (as if opening for the first time) when a user sends it to the background. I'm  guessing I would have to put some code in the appdelegate to manage this. Could anyone provide me a primer on how to do this?

Comment: I think you should read about an app's lifecycle: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

Comment: Apps only suspend when going into the background, so it should stay in the same state... But there are times when it closes (low memory etc.). Have you looked at using `NSUserDefaults` for storing data?

Comment: @jjv - >>Apps only suspend when going into the background, so it should stay in the same state...<< I do agree with that but in my case I am dealing with a sales force of about 1000 people and I can guarantee that by clicking the home button the majority of them think they have closed the app. However, in a suspended state the apps will still have sensitive information, contract numbers, rates, etc. I would rather they have to re-enter the information than leave it there.

Comment: O I thought you wanted it the other way around...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `Application does not run in background` / `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` key in your app's Info.plist file and set it to `YES` and it will always terminate your app when it is put to background, making it start from scratch on next run.

It will esentially turn off multitasking for your app.

Comment: Thanks Filip, I just found that in another SO question.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // app is going to background for whatever reason (but not being killed)
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // app is about to come to the front (but not being launched)
    // reset your ui here
}
```

This is useful if you don't do the other answer but want the app to not be killed. We actually track how long between these two calls and reset after 30 minutes in our case.

Comment: thanks, but I need to not let it go to the background because of the sensitive info that might be on it.